using scss in Expo project -- imported styles object is always empty
I'm using react-native-sass-transformer to use scss in my react native expo project.
To get set up, I ran npm install --save-dev react-native-sass-transformer sass, configured my .metro.config.js and app.json according to the instructions, separated my styles out into a new .scss file, and imported them like this import styles from "./SignInScreen.scss";.
When I print out the value of styles, it is always an empty object ({}). How do I get my styles to import correctly?
If it matters, I am using Expo Go.
Here is my metro.config.js:
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("expo/metro-config");

module.exports = (() => {
  const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

  const { transformer, resolver } = config;

  config.transformer = {
    ...transformer,
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-sass-transformer")
  };

  config.resolver = {
    ...resolver,
    sourceExts: [...resolver.sourceExts, "scss", "sass"]
  };

  return config;
})();

Here is my app.json:
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "packagerOpts": {
      "config": "metro.config.js",
      "sourceExts": ["js", "jsx", "scss", "sass"]
    },
    ...
  }
}

Here is my SignInScreen.scss:
.container {
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 16px;
}

.title {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

.input {
  height: 40px;
  border-color: gray;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

Here is my SignInScreen.js:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard } from 'react-native';
import { firebaseAuth } from '../../firebaseConfig';
import styles from "./SignInScreen.scss";

console.log("styles ", styles);

const SignInScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  {...}

  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Sign In</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Email"
          value={email}
          onChangeText={setEmail}
        />
        {...}
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
};

export default SignInScreen;


I only tried one transformer in the past, but I never got it to have any effect.

did you end up resolving it. In my case, when ever i try to apply the styles like  I get error on style. I am using typescript did you create the declarations.d.ts file too?

I found this issue which is similar to your issue. Link: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/27490
According to mark you should be fine to simply remove react-native-sass-transformer. (Not Tested)
Or downgrade to version 48.
But your code looks good.
